# permissions in if tag discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I’m making a discord bot. In a cog, I use an event that blocks links. I have a problem. The bot will block everyone, even bots and himself to send links. I want to do that if the user has the permissions *manage_messages*, the bot will not block the link. I tried to do this

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if 'https://' in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} don’t send links!")
    elif has_permissions(manage_message=True):
        return
```

I don’t know how to fix it, so please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should combine both cases in one if, since when the first if is True, the second if isn't executed even it it's True:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if 'https://' in message.content and has_permissions(manage_message=False):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} don’t send links!")
```